# Правильная анотация с JOIN (symfony)

Tags: symfony4

Как правильно связать свойства $restrictTag и $banner_id. При insert $banner_id заходит null, а tag работает.

Файл Banner.php

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="banner_id", cascade={"persist", "remove" })
 *  @ORM\JoinTable(name="banner_restrict_tag",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="banner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="banner_id")
 *   }
 * )
 */

private $restrictTag;
```

Файл Tag.php

```
/**

 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Banner", cascade={"persist", "remove" })
 *  @ORM\JoinTable(name="banner",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="banner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $banner_id;
```